# Samu'el meaning

Tags: names, samuel-shmuel-book-of

I already knew the following meanings of the name שמואל Shmuel/Samuel: Name of G-d or G-d has heard.

But then I came across the word sam שם meaning something like to put, to appoint (over).

Could this name also be understand as: He appointed Him as G-d? Or anything in this ditection?

Comment: The word שם when meaning "to put" is spelled with a sin, while Shmuel's name is spelled with a shin.

Comment: In the Torah there is מי יחיה מִשֻּׂמוֹאֵל where it had a sin instead of a shin. The Torah also has שְׁמוּאֵל בן עמיהוד with a shin. Which of those words are you thinking of?

Comment: @YK : Context and grammar determines wheter it is read as a Sin or Shin, so without nikud or interpertations, or by making words out of the letters of this name it might make a difference, or not? P.s see Double AA

Comment: @DoubleAA  both, although different names based on similarity I find them both interesting.

Answer (score 2):

The famous biblical שמואל was named by his mother חנה who explained "[כִּי מֵיְהוָה שְׁאִלְתִּיו](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%90_%D7%90_%D7%9B)" or "because from Hashem he was requested." Apparently according to the verse the name is a contraction of שאול מאל (and I guess חנה thought שמואל flowed off the tongue easier than שאומל).

Comment: Maybe she was also inspired by the existing name שמואל, cf. Numbers 34:20.

Comment: Good point. Edited out "original."

Comment: That wasn't my point (although strictly speaking you are correct). My point regarded your last sentence of why Hannah used the particular contraction that she did. Besides for it possibly rolling off the tongue better, the choice was perhaps inspired by the existing name.

Comment: That's also a good point.

Comment: @DovF It's the Malbim which explains that it is a concoction of two words משאול -מאל right? What does it mean?

Comment: @Levi several commentators say so; it's the simple reading of the verse. It means requested from ה, a reference to חנה's prayer to which שמואל was the answer.